# A burglar or two?

Tags: indefinite-article, listening

In this [audio file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5jOXzxlxbMhSmo5RlE5NWo2YWc/view), at 1:20, shouldn't it be *two burglars*?

Source: *The ILI English Series, Intermediate 1, Student's Book, page 45*

The reporter starts with:

> This is a story about *a burglar* who was caught by a rabbit.

But it finally turns out that there were actually two burglars and he says:

> Police later arrested *the couple*.

I just want to make sure it's the reporter's mistake: is there a contradiction between what the reporter says at the beginning of his report and the final part of his story?

Comment: If you can clearly hear the audio, then you should transcribe it here and clearly explain why you think it should be "two burglars". Otherwise, if you're asking about what they say because you can't hear it clearly, then that's off-topic because we don't generally provide transcriptions.

Comment: I can clearly hear the audio: "_This is a story about a burglar who was caught by a rabbit_", but finally the speaker says: "..._Police later arrested the couple_".

Comment: The audio clearly says "two young thieves". Why should I listen through the rest of the apparently endless stream of stories? At your time of 1:20 it also clearly says "a burglar".

Comment: @WeatherVane: This audio file includes two stories. Would you mind going to 1:13 where the second report starts?

Comment: So it later reports that two people made off. What has this to do with English? Please complain to the news channel about inaccurate reporting. But since their style is hype, it won't do you much good.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's an audio file from an English textbook. I thought there might be a tiny point I didn't notice. Just wanted to make sure. Thanks for the confirmation that it was a mistake in the audio file and thanks for your patience! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for transcription.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I'm not asking for transcription as I can transcribe every single word of this audio file. Maybe I need to paraphrase my question: I know what they say, but I don't understand why there is a contradiction between what the reporter says at the beginning of his report and the final part of his story. Edited my question again.

Comment: If your question doesn't require transcription, it should simply contain all relevant quotes and operate on the assumption that your transcription is accurate (and that it's only your understanding of the language that is potentially lacking), rather than asking for a cross-check on the accuracy of your transcription/understanding/whatever.

Comment: @Max: The question is edited as you said.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I added the main parts of the transcription to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many languages, the word for **one** doubles up as the indefinite article.  However, in English, the indefinite article **a(n)** doesn't carry quite as strong a meaning as the numeral.

For example, if I ask "Have you got a brother?" then someone with two brothers is more likely to give an affirmative response ("Yes, I've got two, actually") than a negative one ("No, I've got two"), whereas in the unlikely event that I asked "Have you got one brother?", I would be asking whether you had exactly one brother.  Similarly, if someone says "I've got a pen", you can't make any assumptions about how many pens they have in total, but if they say "I've got one pen", that is an affirmation about the number of pens they have.

So the contradiction between "a burglar" and "the couple" isn't as strong as the contradiction between "one burglar" and "the couple" would be.

Nevertheless, it does sound a bit odd.

Comment: Great example and explanation! 